# how to train CNN for .csv or .mat files?

Tags: python, csv, file, deep-learning, computer-vision

I had a folder containing 100 csv files (each file has m rows and n columns). I need to train CNN using these files. I know how to train CNN for images. But how to do with csv or mat files. Can anyone provide python code for above
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `numpy` to load `.csv` files into a `np.array`:

```
numpy.loadtxt(open("myfile.csv", "rb"), delimiter=",", skiprows=1) # skiprows because of csv headers
```

For `.mat` files you can use `scipy`:

```
import scipy.io
mat = scipy.io.loadmat('my_mat_file.mat')
```

Comment: thanks for your reply..but what actually I want is how the CNN model will take .csv files from a folder for training and validation. My directory is shown below:                                                   DATA is main folder...subfolders are training_set and test_set.